# Ignore case sensitive in Clojure

Tags: regex, string, replace, clojure

I have this code to replace all store's name is ABC (or Abc ...) to XYZ

```
(def str1 "ABC store of JOHN")
(str/replace (str/lower-case str1) #"abc" "XYZ")

// output: XYZ store of john
// expected: XYZ store of JOHN
```

I don't want to lowercase all the string like that.
But in Clojure, it can't use the regex `/abc/i` with i flag for ignore case sensitive like other languages.

What kind of clojure regex or clojure lib support case sensitive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But in Clojure, it can't use the regex /abc/i

Yes, you can:

```
(let [str1 "ABC store of JOHN"]
    (str/replace str1 #"(?i)abc" "XYZ"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Clojure simply uses slightly different regex language that it inherited from Java, so you need to write regex as following:

```
(str/replace (str/lower-case str1) #"(?:abc)" "XYZ")
```

outputs `"XYZ store of john"`

You can find description of Java's regex language in the [JDK documentation for Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).